# Displaying carousel image on click of Submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a submit button in my MVC3 application.
On click of Submit button i want to display Carousel image on page on modal window. And after all images are displayed i want to redirect it to next page.

```
<input class="getaQuote_btn" type="submit" id="getquote" value="Get quote"/>
```

Could anyone tell me how to do this. I have never used carousel. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

step 1:When you submit this page,open another page which open model window.
step 2:Display Carousel images in this window. for syntax you can visit [JCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html)

step 3:

```
$('.jcarousel').on('itemlastin.jcarousel', 'li', function(event, carousel) {
//Redirect to other page
```

});